# Front end submit form with jquery form plugin

Tags: php

Maybe someone can help me with a small problem I'm having. I'm trying to use this: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ to create a submit form for Wordpress. I've tested it on a regular site(not WP) and it works. I can't figure out why it won't work in wp.

This is my form. I've created two page templates, one has the form, the other has the wp_insert_post code. If I change the form action to action="http://mysite.com/page.php" it works, if I point it to a page template it doesn't. I need it to point to a page template for the wp_insert_post code to work.

This is on one first page:

```
<form id="myForm" action="http://mysite.com/submitest" method="post"> 
Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you need the second template at all? I mean are you showing anything regarding the processing of this form on the second template? I think its not a very good idea to put your post insertion code (or any heavy processing code, for that matter) in a page template. 
`functions.php` is the RIGHT place for putting your post insertion code. You could get the form data, insert the post, and redirect to the page that has the second template applied.

Comment: that's how the example that I downloaded from here looked like. Two pages one with the form and the other with the processing code. How do I get the form data in functions.php?

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave the action value as blank. Give the `submit` button a name as `name='form_sub'`. Then add the following code to your `functions.php` file. Check the codex for [`init`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) hook. 
You can create a 'Thank You' page, or a confirmation page where the user should go after successful submission.

```
<?php
add_action('init', 'form_submit');

function form_submit(){
    if(isset($_POST['form_sub']))
    {
        //here you'll have your form data in a $_POST array, you can check it using a print_r. parse the form and insert the post
        $title = $_POST['name'];
        $content = $_POST['comment'];

        //change the category and author as you want
        $post_obj = array(
                        'post_title' => $title,
                        'post_content' => $content,
                        'post_category' => array(1), //Uncategorized
                        'post_status' => 'draft',
                        'post_author' => 1 //Admin
                       );
        $id = wp_insert_post($post_obj);

        //check if successfully submitted
        if(isset($id) && !is_wp_error($id))
        {
            //redirect to a thank you page, make sure the slug is 'thank-you'
            wp_redirect(home_url('/thank-you'));
            exit;
        } 
    }
}
?>
```

Try this. Let me know if you are stuck.

Edit:
This is how the form template should be. The submit button should have the name attribute, not the form.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Submit */ ?> 
<?php get_header(); ?> 
Form this: 
<form action="" method="post"> 
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
    Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="form_sub" />
</form>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Check the code!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried a few times but nothing is submitting. I ll do a few more tests and let you know.

Comment: It's still not working. This is what I have on my template page `<?php
/*
Template Name: Submit
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
Form this
<form action="" name="form_sub" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
    Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>

<?php get_footer(); ?>` I checked everything and can't seem to find where the mistake is.

Comment: btw, how do you post your code? I add the two `` but my comment doesn't look like yours.

Comment: Enter twice, leave 4 spaces (that's a tab in a normal editor) and start typing your code. Keep the 4 spaces consistent throughout your code. Backticks are good only for single lines of code. Note: This formatting will work only for an answer, not a comment.

Comment: aha. cool. any idea why the submit is not working?

Comment: Have you given it a name attribute?

Comment: yes. name="form_sub". just like in my comment above.

Comment: I've edited my answer again. Please check.

Comment: yup! that worked. You did say that in your original answer, I just didn't read it carefully enough. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: One last question. Do any additional security measures need to be implemented in this?

Comment: Yes... measures to filter the input data before you insert the post, so as to avoid spamming or sql injections.

Comment: Hey, if you have a chance, would this be the correct way of securing ? `$title = $_POST['name'] = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $_POST['name'] );
        $content = $_POST['comment'] = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $_POST['comment'] );
        $email = $_POST['email'] = is_email( $_POST['email'] );
        $url = $_POST['url'] = esc_url( $_POST['url'] );`

Comment: Seems ok... but I think esc_attr [http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_attr] will do a better job, as it will encode the content, not strip it.

Comment: Please take long discussions in chat, system flagged this as too many comments. :)

Comment: I apologize for that @Rarst! Actually this question has been answered already, but @ciprian comes up with more doubts and adds them as comments! Next time he wants an answer, we're moving to chat! :D

Comment: I'll try it. Thanks for all your help. And sorry about the chat like comments @Rarst. I'll keep it shorter next time.

Comment: why in the function if I try to use the global variables are null?

Comment: Because as far as I know, `init` hook runs before anything else. Infact even the conditional tags are unavailable in `init` hook.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde, I tried this code . But after submit the result is shown and the form disappears while the same page still keeps displaying. Any suggestion ?

Comment: @ciprian, I asked a question to Rutwick . can you have a look at it?